# Does EdDSA share Schnorr signature secure linearity property?

Tags: signature, ed25519, schnorr-signature, eddsa

EdDSA, Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm (EdDSA), is a digital signature scheme using a variant of Schnorr signature based on Twisted Edwards curves ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA)).

Schnorr signatures have a remarkable property: linearity. This allows multiple parties to collaborate to produce a valid signature for the sum of their public keys.

1. Does EdDSA provide the same security guarantees when aggregating signatures or deriving a new signature?
2. Can we apply the same blind signature schema of Schnorr for EdDSA?
3. **If yes, what are the secure EdDSA aggregation constructions?**

I found the following constructions for EdDSA, but I'm not sure if they have been analysed enough:

- [Aggregated Ed25519 Signatures](https://github.com/KZen-networks/multi-party-eddsa/wiki/Aggregated-Ed25519-Signatures)
- [Compact Multi-Signatures for SmallerBlockchains](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/483.pdf)

Comment: There is also a new protocol supporting half-aggregation in a non-interactive way (presented to this year's CT-RSA): Non-interactive half-aggregation of EdDSA and variants of Schnorr signatures https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/350